# Shmuel on Bava Basra 90a

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

> ‫ והמשתכר אל ישתכר יותר משתות (בבא בתרא 90A)‬
> "One who gets drunk may not get drunk past a sixth."

I have seen four shittos to explain this ruling which is brought l'halacha in O"C Siman 683.

> Panim Chalashos (OC 883:2) says that one who reaches ad d'lo yada and wishes to continue drinking must make each drink 1/6 the size of the previous one until he asymptotically approaches either zero or the inability to say asymptotically whichever comes first.
>
> Ta"m (Turei mashke) ad loc points out that Ta'us sofrim records שתות as a copyist error and that the correct girsa is שטות i.e. one should not drink past the point when he begins to act like an idiot. If he does, then chazrah hamekach and the owner of the liquor store is permitted to take back his wine.
>
> Magen Avraham challenges the Ta"M and asks how he can pasken based on this obscure rishon and completely dismiss the longstanding minhag yisroel to drink far past that point. The original girsa stands but shtus does *not* mean 1/6 *of* the previous drink but 1/6 *more* so that if you start with a 6 ounce glass, your second drink should be 7 ounces and so on.
>
> משנה בירה paskens like Magen Avraham but adds that a baal nefesh should add a sixth mil'bar.

How are we machriah l'mayseh?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: מסתברא like the Magen Avraham because מעלין בקודש ואין מורידין.

Answer (score 2):

This is to avoid anyone's drinking an entire fifth. Asu syag lapurim torah.

Comment: Ah, so you're offering a new pshat that it means to drink a sixth of whiskey?

Comment: well, there are later meforshim who say "a sixth whiskey" as opposed to a "sixth OF whiskey" but I'm a traditionalist.

Answer (score 1):

This opinion argues on the opinion that one should drink "Ad Delo Yada", as it says "Don't drink more than [will make you do] Shtus".

We the halacha is that we drink enough to get one drunk. The reason is that since Purim is the highest holiday, it must be greater than Pesach. As we drink Ad Delo Yada on Pesach (which is why Echad - Mi Yodeya -- First things first, are we at a state of Ad Delo Yada yet), all the more so on Purim.

Comment: Sir, you are violating my trademark.